# How to deal with mapStateToProps() function when doing two different actions on the same page?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-navigation

After 2 days of research from my side hope I will find an answer here !

I'm calling an API to retrieve a list of films. Films are displayed into a view called "new films"

Inside this view, I have two possibilities : put a film as favorite (by clicking on the "heart" icon) AND click on the blue button which say "I saw this film"

To do this I'm using react-redux.
Until now, when I put a film as favorite it works; The state changes (see mapStateToProps() function) and I retrieve this film by clicking on the tab of navigation bar below (see attached file)

Now, I'm trying to do approximatively the same thing on the same class "FilmDetail" when I click on the button "I saw this film" except films will appear in the "viewed" tab instead (see attached file).

So my question is how to create another mapStateToProps() in the same class to change the state and make the film appear in the "seen" tab ?

I tried to do the stuff in the componentDidMount() function but it doesn't work.
Maybe there's a concept of react-redux I don't know yet.

this is the full code (it works for favorites page)

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Share, Platform, View, Text, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView, Image, 
TouchableOpacity, Button } from 'react-native'
import { getFilmDetailFromApi, getImageFromApi } from '../API/TMDBApi'
import moment from 'moment'
import numeral from 'numeral'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import EnlargeShrink from'../Animations/EnlargeShrink'
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'


if (__DEV__) {
  NativeModules.DevSettings.setIsDebuggingRemotely(true)
}



class FilmDetail extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions= ({ navigation }) => {
      const { params } = navigation.state
      // On accède à la fonction shareFilm et au film via les paramètres qu'on a ajouté à la navigation
      if (params.film != undefined && Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        return {
            // On a besoin d'afficher une image, il faut donc passe par une Touchable une fois de plus
    headerRight: <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.share_touchable_headerrightbutton}
                    onPress={() => params.shareFilm()}>
                  <Image
                      style={styles.share_image}
                      source={require('../Images/ic_share.png')} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
        }
      }
  }

constructor (props){
  super (props)
  this.state={
    film: undefined,
    isLoading: false
  }
  this._shareFilm = this._shareFilm.bind(this)

}
_updateNavigationParams() {
   this.props.navigation.setParams({
     shareFilm: this._shareFilm,
     film: this.state.film
   })
 }
componentDidMount() {
    const favoriteFilmIndex = this.props.favoritesFilm.findIndex(item => item.id === this.props.navigation.state.params.idFilm)
    if (favoriteFilmIndex !== -1) { // Film déjà dans nos favoris, on a déjà son détail
      // Pas besoin d'appeler l'API ici, on ajoute le détail stocké dans notre state global au state de notre component
      this.setState({
        film: this.props.favoritesFilm[favoriteFilmIndex]
      }, () => { this._updateNavigationParams() })
      return
    }
    // Le film n'est pas dans nos favoris, on n'a pas son détail
    // On appelle l'API pour récupérer son détail
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    getFilmDetailFromApi(this.props.navigation.state.params.idFilm).then(data => {
      this.setState({
        film: data,
        isLoading: false
      }, () => { this._updateNavigationParams()})
  })}




  _shareFilm(){
    const { film } = this.state
    Share.share({ title: film.title, message: film.overview })
  }
 _displayFloatingActionButton(){
   const { film } = this.state
   if ( film != undefined && Platform.OS === 'android') {
     return (
       <TouchableOpacity
         style={styles.share_touchable_floatingactionbutton}
         onPress={() => this._shareFilm()}>
         <Image
           style={styles.share_image}
           source={require('../Images/ic_share.png')} />
       </TouchableOpacity>
     )
   }
 }

_displayLoading(){
  if (this.state.isLoading){
    return(
      <View style={styles.Loading_container}>
        <ActivityIndicator size='large'/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

  _toggleFavorite() {
      const action = { type: "TOGGLE_FAVORITE", value: this.state.film }
      this.props.dispatch(action)
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.props.favoritesFilm);
  }

  _displayFavoriteImage() {
    var sourceImage = require('../Images/ic_favorite_border.png')
    var shouldEnlarge= false //si le film n'est pas en favoris on veut qu'au en clic sur le button, celui-ci s'agrandise => shouldEnlarge a true!
      if (this.props.favoritesFilm.findIndex (item => item.id ===  this.state.film.id) !== -1)
   {
      // Film dans nos favoris
      sourceImage = require('../Images/ic_favorite.png')
      shouldEnlarge= true
    }

    return (
      <EnlargeShrink
        shouldEnlarge= {shouldEnlarge}>
     <Image
       style={styles.favorite_image}
       source={sourceImage}
     />
   </EnlargeShrink>
   )

}

_displayFilm(){
  const {film}= this.state
  if(film != undefined) {
    return(
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollview_container}>
        <Image
           style={styles.image}
           source={{uri: getImageFromApi(film.backdrop_path)}}
         />
         <Text style={styles.title_text}>{film.title}</Text>

           <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.favorite_container}
      onPress={() => this._toggleFavorite()}>
      {this._displayFavoriteImage()}
          </TouchableOpacity>

         <Text style={styles.description_text}>{film.overview}</Text>
         <Text style={styles.default_text}>Sorti le {moment(new Date(film.release_date)).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</Text>
         <Text style={styles.default_text}>Note : {film.vote_average} / 10</Text>
         <Text style={styles.default_text}>Nombre de votes : {film.vote_count}</Text>
         <Text style={styles.default_text}>Budget : {numeral(film.budget).format('0,0[.]00 $')}</Text>
         <Text style={styles.default_text}>Genre(s) : {film.genres.map(function(genre){
             return genre.name;
           }).join(" / ")}
         </Text>
         <Text style={styles.default_text}>Companie(s) : {film.production_companies.map(function(company){
             return company.name;
           }).join(" / ")}
         </Text>

      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
state={
  toggle: false
}
_toggleVus(){
  const newState = !this.state.toggle;
  this.setState({toggle:newState})

}


  render() {


    const {toggle} = this.state;
    const textValue= toggle?"Non vu":"Marquer comme vu";
    console.log(this.props);

    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        {this._displayFilm()}
        {this._displayLoading()}
        {this._displayFloatingActionButton()}
        <View >
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Buttom}
        onPress={() =>this._toggleVus()}>
         <Text style={styles.text}>{textValue}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    flex: 1,
  },

Loading_container:{
  position: 'absolute',
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center'
},
scrollview_container:{
  flex: 1,
},
image: {
   height: 169,
   margin: 5
 },
 title_text: {
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   fontSize: 35,
   flex: 1,
   flexWrap: 'wrap',
   marginLeft: 5,
   marginRight: 5,
   marginTop: 10,
   marginBottom: 10,
   color: '#000000',
   textAlign: 'center'
 },
 description_text: {
   fontStyle: 'italic',
   color: '#666666',
   margin: 5,
   marginBottom: 15
 },
 default_text: {
   marginLeft: 5,
   marginRight: 5,
   marginTop: 5,
 },
 favorite_container:{
   alignItems: 'center'

 },
 favorite_image:{
   flex: 1,
   width: null,
   height: null
 },
 share_touchable_floatingactionbutton:{
   position: 'absolute',
   width: 60,
   height: 60,
   right: 30,
   bottom: 30,
   borderRadius: 30,
   backgroundColor: '#e91e63',
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center'
 },
 share_image:{
   width: 30,
   height: 30
 },
 share_touchable_headerrightbutton: {
   marginRight: 8
 },
 Buttom:{

   backgroundColor:'dodgerblue',
   justifyContent:'center'
 },
 text:{
   textAlign:'center',
   fontSize: 19,
   color:'white'

 }
})
const mapStateToProps= (state) =>{
  return {
    favoritesFilm: state.toggleFavorite.favoritesFilm
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FilmDetail)
```

And this is what I need to do now :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't Clearly understand what you mean but it is possible to add multiple states in the mapStateToProps to props like this , you dont need to create another function, as long as you deal with it also from the store

```
    const mapStateToProps= (state) =>{
      return {
        favoritesFilm: state.toggleFavorite.favoritesFilm,
        SeenFilm: state.any_store_state
    }
  }
```